# Searching by text, using mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I am trying to do a text search of the collection called `DAFacility` in MongoDB Compass:

```
_id:62170597b3fa8994a0d9a0c8
author:"User"
organizationName:"TSTT"
eventName:"Facility Assessment After Disaster"
eventDate:2022-02-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
area:"Siparia"
disasterNature:"Earthquake"
threatLevel:"High"
surroundingDamage:"Cracked Foundations and Roads"
facilityName:"Point Lisas Main Facility"
facLocation:Array
facStatus:"Operable"
operEqu:23
inoperEqu:7
facilityDamage:"Cracked Walls and Floors"
facImage:Array
__v:0
```

I am trying to search the field `facilityDamage` where i can search maybe one word from the entire data entry (eg searching the word `"Walls"` and having the entire entry shows up)

I am trying to perform it within mongoDB data aggregation option with the template being:

```
[
    {
        '$search': {
            'index': 'string', 
            'text': {
                'query': 'string', 
                'path': 'string'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have read the document which got me more confused as to what goes in the index, query and path.
can you all advise me as to what variables goes into index, query and path.

Whenever i use it within node it returns an empty array:

```
exports.DAEquipment_damage_search = (req, res) => {
  DAEquipment.aggregate([
    [
      {
        '$match': {
        '$or': [
           {'facilityDamage':{ '$regex':'.*' + req.body.facilityDamage + '.*','$options': 'i' } }
        ]
    }
    }
    }
  ]
  ]).then((DAEquipment) => {
    res.send(DAEquipment);
    console.log(DAEquipment);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    res.send(e);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await DAFacility.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
           {"facilityDamage":{ $regex:'.*' + searchText + '.*',$options: 'i' } },
        ]
    }
},
])
```

May it will help you

Comment: Hey i just made an edit to the main question, can you take a look...i am trying to integrate it with node however it is returning an empty array even though the database contains the fields

Comment: Hey,
kindly please check with the static word 

ex.
{
        '$match': {
        '$or': [
           {'facilityDamage':{ '$regex':'.*' + 'Walls' + '.*','$options': 'i' } }
        ]
}

if it's worked please check your req.body params